# Create Function Command for Derby Database

Tags: java, derby

I am having trouble using Create Function Command for Derby Database.

To start with I tried

```
  CREATE FUNCTION TO_DEGREES(RADIANS DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA
  EXTERNAL NAME 'java.lang.Math.toDegrees'
```

and then

```
 SELECT TO_DEGREES(3.142), BILLNO FROM SALEBILL
```

This works absolutely fine.

Now I tried making my own function like this :

```
package SQLUtils;
public final class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
    }

    public static int addNos(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return(val1+val2);
    }
 }
```

followed by

```
CREATE FUNCTION addno(no1 int, no2 int) RETURNS int
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'SQLUtils.TestClass.addNos'
```

and then

```
SELECT addno(3,4), BILLNO FROM SALEBILL
```

This gives an Exception

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X51: The class 'SQLUtils.TestClass' does not exist or is inaccessible. This   can happen if the class is not public.
```

Error code 99999, SQL state XJ001: Java exception: 'SQLUtils.TestClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'.

Line 6, column 1

I have made a jar file of the project containing the above Class.  I may be wrong but the conclusion that I can draw from this is that this jar file needs to be in some classpath. But in which classpath and how to add it to a classpath, I am not able to understand.

I tried copying the jar file to jdk\lib folder, jre\lib folder, jdk\jre\lib folder but to no avail.

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1.2, jdk 1.7.0_09, Derby version 10.8.1.2 in Network mode. The applications and data are on a Server. I access them from Netbeans installed on client computer.

Comment: You did copy the jar file to the **server**, right? For defining the classpath see here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdeploy15818.html

Comment: I tried copying it on the Server. I setup the data and application on the same computer. Didn't work. Your link to the developer guide suggests adding the jar file to the database. THAT WORKED !!! THANKS a TON for that buddy. P.S. Even that guide quotes "**Derby first looks in the user's classpath before looking in the database.**" but I am not able to do that. Any Help in that direction would be highly appreciated :)